# Clear Notification from other apps with deleteIntent, cancelNotification, or both?

Tags: android, notifications

Notification.deleteIntent does a nice job clearing notifications, but many apps that generate Notifications leave this null.

NotificiationListenerService.cancelNotification(pkg, tag, id) also works to clear notifications, but sometimes (not always) results in a PendingIntent.CanceledException if called after sending the deleteIntent.

What is the preferred logic to clear notifications from other apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NotificationListenerService.cancelNotification executes the Notification.deleteIntent.

There does not appear to be any benefit to using .deleteIntent explicitly. It appears to do the exact same thing as .cancelNotification in google apps like gmail, but is actually less functional for 3rd party apps like facebook which do not remove the notification when sending the .deleteIntent.

Comment: If sending deleteIntent doesn't remove the notifications of some apps like facebook, then how does swiping the notification on the phone or swiping it on a watch, remove the notification from the phone? If the deleteIntent is null, then what is fired when we swipe the notification? Thanks!